# Do these two snippets return the same value?

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm not sure how to title this question, but it's concerning a pattern where the `||` operator is used to resolve a sequence of undefined values to the first defined one.

Are these equivalent?

```
export function getRuntime(): Runtime {
  return runtime || findWindow() || mockWindow;
}
```

and

```
export function getRuntime(): Runtime {
  if (runtime) return runtime;
  if (findWindow()) return findWindow();
  return mockWindow;
}
```

Comment: Yes, they both do the same thing. The second one could also be written with `else` branches.

Comment: Yes, the only difference is that, in the second case, if `findWindow()` returns a truthy value it will get called twice

Comment: So it's important that `findWindow()` doesn't have any side-effect. The same concept is applicable to `runtime` if it has defined a getter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both of the code snippets do the same thing, as the `||` and `return` is simply doing the same thing as returning from the `if` statements.

The only difference between the two is that if `findWindow()` returns a value which is considered `true` in JavaScript, it will run twice. This *"issue"* only occurs in the second one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, both functions do the same thing.